# JavaScript Functions Not Synchronized

Tags: javascript

I have created a JavaScript program that is intended to run on multiple computers at once.
I need to know how to run a function on all of the computers at the same time.

I have tried making a function that uses `setTimeout` to basically wait until a certain time. I have done multiple checks on both computers and it seems to think that it is making up for `setTimeout`'s delay, but it is still off by around 0.4 seconds.

Comment: That's not really possible. Why would you need such a specific requirement? Sounds like you are overcomplicating a problem.

Comment: @cloned If you must know, I am creating a Rubik's cube racing timer for people in quarantine.

Comment: OK, let's step back. Rubik's cube competitions are fine IRL but if you're on a computer, why does it need to happen simultaneous? It seems perfectly reasonable for people to start this a minute before or after. Or even hours and days later. Just let user A start when they want, then once they finish record their time and submit it to a server. Done. Now when user B comes in the next day, they can "race" user A by competing against their time. You can even simulate as if it's real time by showing a "scoreboard" that depends on submitted times. When user Z tries it, they'll race 25 others.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree, but I would like it if it's in real-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize your applications either using a central server with Websockets, for example. Or, if you want to use something really fancy, you can use WebRTC signalling. It is a bit harder to get into, but it works brilliantly.

Update: I just read that you want to use it for a Rubik's cube competition? With WebRTC, you can even integrate a live video connection between both players so that they can see their opponents cube. Sounds fun!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 100% guarantee that the function will run at the same time on both the computers. Even with Websockets there will be a network delay to reach each computer and you cannot guarantee network message will reach to all computers at the same time.

Comment: I know that it can't be 100% accurate, but I'm just trying to avoid 0.2s and above of delay.